# SQL display age range

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a query for age range, in which I want to show the count of people of all age ranges eg

```
    AGE   PEOPLE
   "0-10"  0
   "11-20" 2
   "21-30" 5
   "31-40" 0
   "41-50" 1
```

I've tried using

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN age < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Under 10],
        SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [11-20],
        SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [21-30]
 FROM people
```

But it shows ranges as column names

```
   0-10  11-20 21-30 31-40 41-50
     0     2     5     0    1
```

which i dont want.

I have also tried GROUP BY but it didn't show the ranges in which the count was 0.

Comment: Create a help table (or recursive cte) with the age groups, min and max year. Outer join that table and group by the result.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```sql
SELECT '[Under 10]' as Age, SUM(CASE WHEN age < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as People
FROM people
UNION ALL
SELECT '[11-20]', SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM people
UNION ALL
SELECT '[21-30]', SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM people;
```

Comment: not what i want, i want 2 coulmns "age" and "count"
and then their results in rows

Comment: The least efficient way to do it. At least do UNION ALL.

Answer (score 3):

you case when should be like below

```
CASE WHEN age < 10 then '0-10'
     when age age BETWEEN 11 AND 20 then '11-20'
     when age BETWEEN 21 AND 30 then '21-30'
     ..... end as agegroup,--put here more according to your need
     count(*)
from table group by agegroup
```

Comment: i've tried this too but it doesn't show rows in which the count is 0, suppose in my table there's no person between age 0-10 but i want that row to be shown in my result with its count as 0

Comment: @smith  in this way you can find final result

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform `UNION All` for this.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN age < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PEOPLE, 'UNDER 10' AS AGE FROM people
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PEOPLE, `11-20` FROM people
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) , `21-30` FROM people
```

You want to get the group of result in rows so need to perform `UNION` in this case.
Please find this link for more info on `UNION` in MYSQL.[link](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/union_all.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use `UNION`, use `UNION ALL` and move the conditions to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT '[Under 10]' as Age, COUNT(*)
FROM people
WHERE age < 10
UNION
SELECT '[11-20]', COUNT(*)
FROM people
WHERE BETWEEN 11 AND 20
UNION ALL
SELECT '[21-30]', COUNT(*)
FROM people
WHERE age BETWEEN 21 AND 30;
```

Filtering and `UNION ALL` both improve performance.  (`UNION` incurs overhead for removing duplicates).

There are other approaches.  For instance, you can unpivot your table:

```
SELECT grp.age,
       (CASE grp
            WHEN 1 THEN [Under 10]
            WHEN 2 THEN [11-20]
            WHEN 3 THEN [21-30]
        END)
FROM (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN age < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Under 10]
             SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [11-20],
             SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [21-30]
      FROM people p
     ) p CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT 1 as grp, '[Under 10]' as age UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 as grp, '[11-20]' as age UNION ALL
      SELECT 3, as grp, '[21-30]' as age
     ) grps;
```

Although this looks more complicated, it is much better from a performance perspective, because it only scans the original table once.

There are other variants as well that only touch the original table once.